# Type mismatch on query to create an array from list

Tags: vba, excel

I am running some VBa code in Excel to update multiple sheets, based on a list of sheets names.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ArrayOne As Variant
ArrayOne = ActiveSheet.Range("A8:A10")

Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayOne)

Dim target As Range
Dim sheetObject As Worksheet

' change value of range 'a1' on each sheet from sheetsArray
For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
    Set target = sheetObject.Range("A1")
    target.Value = "Test"
Next sheetObject
End Sub
```

Here is my code, unfortuantly it errors: Type Mismatch on the following line of code

```
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayOne)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm understanding that you want to update the same cells in each worksheet, based on a list of worksheets that is contained in an Excel Range (A8:A10).

Try the following code:

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim WksCell As Range

  ' Turn on inline Error Handling
  On Error Resume Next

  ' Look at each cell within the range and obtain worksheet names
  For Each WksCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A8:A10").Cells

    ' Attempt to reference the worksheet using this name
    Set wks = Excel.Worksheets(WksCell.Value)

    ' Check if a "SubScript out of range" error occurred
    ' If so, it indicates that the sheet name does not exist
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
      ' Set its style to Bad and move on
      WksCell.Style = "Bad"
      Err.Clear
    Else
      ' For each worksheet, execute our logic
      wks.Range("A1").Value = "Testing"
    End If

    ' If any other error occurred, report it to the user and exit
    If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 9 Then
      MsgBox "An error has occurred. Error #" & Err.Number & vbCr & _ 
              Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Encountered"
      Set wks = Nothing
      Exit For
    End If

  Next
  ' Return to normal error handling
  On Error GoTo 0
  Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you'd rather use it in a Macro then you can change the line

```
For Each WksCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A8:A10").Cells
```

to

```
For Each WksCell In Excel.Selection
```

which will use your current selection as the Worksheet list.  Makes it more dynamic.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont think it does. I am trying to update multiple sheets at the same time. I have a list of the sheet names that I need to target, hence the array.

Comment: I have adapted the following code, however my sheet list needs to be dynamic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745459/reference-multiple-sheets-in-one-line

Comment: Thanks, but I have an unspecified number of sheets, so I need the code to be dynamic - It looks like with your code I will need to know the sheet names and specify them upfront?

Comment: Added Comments, Error Handling, and Macro Option to the code for anyone else stumbling across this page.